# How to automatically manipulate an html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm doing automation test for an html5 video related project.

**Goal: When I run my script, the embedded video would automatically start, pause and jump to some specific point.**

```
<video controls="controls" id="asset-element" class="video-asset" preload="auto" allowfullscreen="">
            <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

I'm able to start the video only because there is a 'start button' image on video landing page, which triggers an event:

```
<img id="playButton" class="play-button" src="sample.png" onclick="showVideoAndPlay()"\>
```

and following code would do the 'start' work:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('playButton')).click();
```

However, I don't know how to pause this video or seek to any point.

Is there any js libs for doing it?

I tried to pause like this:

```
var video = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('asset-element'));
video.pause();
```

But it throws:

```
video.pause();
      ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pause'
```

Appreciate it in advance!

Comment: Reading the spec might help you http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html

Comment: There is no direct way. Normally you would use `storeEval` in Selenium to run JS to interact with the DOM API For controlling the video, but I can't find mention of that in the Node.JS Webdriver library. It might be undocumented or it might be unsupported. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: @Quentin the following page says, you are wrong: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ReeCube — That page is talking about JavaScript embedded in the webpage, not JavaScript controlling a Selenium instance (which is what this question is about). You could use the information in that page to construct the JS that gets injected into the page with `storeEval` as mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @Quentin ah right, I'm sorry, missunderstood it